# How do I populate the FastAPI I'm building with data from a separate JSON file?

Tags: python, json, api, pycharm, fastapi

I realize this is likely a very simple answer, but have been unable to find any sort of tutorial or example of how to do this online. I am making a basic app that displays the schedule for a college orientation week, and want to pull the events from an API so that, in case any times/dates change, the API can be updated by and the app deployed on everyone's phones will receive the updated info when it calls to the API.

[image: app mockup]

*(here is the mockup for the app)*

For my API, I'm using FastAPI in pycharm. I understand the structure of the API, but every example/tutorial only shows how to return things like "hello world", not actual data. For example, what I want is for *[www.example.com/all-events](http://www.example.com/all-events)* to return

```
{
            "Calendar ": "Orientation Team",
            "eventName": "Set up check-in",
            "Date": "8/24/21",
            "Time": "7:00 AM",
            "Location": "dining hall",
            "eventID": "1"
        },
        {
            "Calendar ": "Orientation Team",
            "eventName": "First-Year check-in",
            "Date": "8/24/21",
            "Time": "8:00AM-11:00AM",
            "eventID": "2"
        },
```

et cetra, and for *[www.example.com/eventid=2](http://www.example.com/eventid=2)* to return

```
{
            "Calendar ": "Orientation Team",
            "eventName": "First-Year check-in",
            "Date": "8/24/21",
            "Time": "8:00AM-11:00AM",
            "eventID": "2"
        }
```

How do I parse through my JSON file in my API, and have it publish so that my app can access it? For example,

```
api.post 
for (int x, x<OrientationData.length, x++)
{
if (OrientationData[x].date=="8/24/21")
 {  
    return OrientationData[x]
}
```

So that this URI would return all events happening on 8/24.

My current code for the API is this:

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
app = FastAPI()


class Event (BaseModel):
    eventName: str
    eventID: int
    eventCalendar: str
    date: str
    time: str
    location: str


@app.get("/")
def home():
    return {"Hello": "FastAPI"}

@app.post('/event')
async def create_event(event: Event):
    return event
```

Comment: How are you loading your JSON file into Python? What is the format of the file? Do you want to return all fields in the file? You'll have to add routes for `/all-events` and `/events/{event_id}` and add the relevant code for those portions. The SQL database tutorial in the FastAPI documentation should give you examples of how to return more data: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#read-data (in general; you can just return the data, and it'll be properly formatted as JSON in the response)

Comment: @MatsLindh I have a main.py file and a OrientationData.json file right now; for some reason when I try to do [import OrientationData] or [import OrientationData.json]  in my main.py file, it doesn't recognize OrientationData as existing, even though it's in the same SRC folder. However, if I change the file name to OrientationData.py, it has no problem importing, but that of course is not a solution because the JSON can't be in a .py file. I created a __init__.py file, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: You use the `json` module in Python for loading JSON files - JSON files aren't valid python modules (which is what you import with `import`). `orientations = json.load("OrientationData.json")` would read in the contents of the json file to the `orientations` variable.